# finding all substrings that fit a certain format

Tags: java, regex, string, substring

Lets say I have a String text such that:

```
System.out.println(text);
//output: laksjdlkja"a$b$c"askjd"asdafar"rafs$"asdk"xx$re$odiff"kdf
```

I wanna find all substrings of text that have the format "_ $ _ $ _" (where _ can be anything except `"` and `$`).

In this case, after the lookup, I would like to have a String array with the content

```
"a$b$c"
"xx$re$odiff"
```

How can I do this lookup?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one option using a regex pattern matcher, with the following pattern:

```
[^"$]+\$[^"$]+\$[^"$]+
```

Sample code:

```
String text = "laksjdlkja\"a$b$c\"askjd\"asdafar\"rafs$\"asdk\"xx$re$odiff\"kdf";
String pattern = "[^\"$]+\\$[^\"$]+\\$[^\"$]+";

Pattern r = Pattern.compile(pattern);
Matcher m = r.matcher(text);
while (m.find()) {
     System.out.println("Found match: " + m.group(0));
}

Found match: a$b$c
Found match: xx$re$odiff
```